# Quarkus native mode - Provider for javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be found

Tags: java, xml, docker, quarkus

I have problem with quarkus in native mode (on docker image), because everything is working fine locally.

Request should return XML body, and it's working when I run it not in container. Here is my resource class:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/generate")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public ExampleClass generate() {
        return service.generate();
    }
```

My entity has annotations from `javax.xml.bind.annotation` and for parser `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation` :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "test")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"header", "body"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

When I tried use this in container, there is error:

> ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /generate failed, error id: 7ac5346a-d72b-4ff3-9948-4ea6b8a026ce-2: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be found

> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be found

I've tried add XMLInputFactory to reflection, but it didn't change anything.

Dependencies which I've used:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Really thank You for any hint.

EDIT:
This problem has needed create **resources-config.json** with *xml* libraries.
After add: JAXBContextFactory, XMLInputFactory, XMLOutputFactory exception's changed for:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created
(...)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created
(...)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found
```

Any ideas?
Adding WstxInputFactory to resource files didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except **resources-config.json** file, it needed **reflection-config.json** with lacked classes (to force *quarkus* load them). It's probably a workaround, but I coulnd't find better solution.

**reflection-config.json** :

```
[
  {
    "name" : "com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  },
  {
    "name" : "com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  }
]
```